# How can I use variable request in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a model called Session, and in it I need to save a column of user IP. However, the model can not see the variable "request".

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_ip

  [...]

  def set_ip
    self.ip = request.remote_ip
  end
end
```

What is the most elegant way, without breaking the MVC pattern, to solve this problem?

Comment: add an action in controller or helper and pass the fetched `request` to model.

Comment: I don't know your context, but if you're just looking to implement some user access, with sessions, registrations, etc. you should use the [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). Easy to configure and override if you need to do more complicated things.

Comment: @CyrilDD Thanks, but I know this gem, but I'm with manually implementing learning purposes only

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be something like this :D. As @uDaY said, you should do this in your controller. You can extract this ip variable and insert it in your form params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

    def your_action
      Session.do_something(session_params) # do_something can be .new, .update, etc. depending on your action
    end

    private
    def session_params
          p = params.require(:session).permit(
            :your_stuff,
            ...
          )
          p[:ip] = request.remote_ip
    end

end
```

Then in your model/database, you can just define a column/field `ip`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it in from your controller:

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base

  def initialize(ip)
    @ip = ip
  end

end

class SomeController
  def new_session
    Session.new(request.remote_ip)
    Session.save
  end
end
```

I used the `initialize` method here but you could just pass it into an existing method if that's more convenient for your use case.